# Discrete convolution norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $b \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$. Define $T:l^2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ by 
$$ (Tx)_n = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{n-m}x_m $$.

I need to prove that $\|T\| \leq \|b\|_{l^1}$.

I know that this is a direct result of [Young's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality). Is there a direct way to show this for the discrete convolution above, without using Young's Inequality?

Comment: @kimchilover, no, I mean discrete convolution operator, the one that I wrote

Answer (score 1):

Young's inequality holds for any unimodular group. $\mathbb{Z}$ is unimodular. Hence the proof via Young's inequality works for discrete convolution as well.

Comment: Thanks but I meant a direct way without using Young's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can argue that $\|T\|=1$ for the special case that $T$ is a shift operator (that is, $b_i=1$ for one particular $i$ value, otherwise $b_i=0$).  Then, since $T\mapsto \|T\|$ is convex, you know your inequality for all finitely supported $b$.  If there exists a unit vector  $x\in l^2(\mathbb Z)$ for which  $\|Tx\|_2>\|b\|_1$, you should be able to derive a contradiction.